# history.back() and history.go(-1) does not work on Chrome but do in Firefox. Why?

Tags: javascript

I have an `<a>` link that when someone press it, it redirects the user to the previous page. Seems to be working on Firefox, but not on Safari, Chrome or Edge (Chromium). But, why? I tried with `history.back()`, `history.go(-1)`, adding "`return false`" to the `onClick` statement at the end (as I saw on other posts before), but nothing seems to fix it.

Also, no error is present on the JavaScript Console, so I have no idea what the hell is wrong.

Thanks.

Edit: Thanks to @Bergi and @marcobiedermann for the solution: `<a onClick="event.preventDefault(); history.goBack()" href="example.com"></a>`

Comment: According to MDN this is supported in Chrome from version 1: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/back
When using an `<a>` element, you have to prevent the default (`prevent.default()`) behavior. In this case, I rather recommend using a `<button>` instead of an `<a>

Comment: I know it's weird, but using: `<a onClick="history.back(); prevent.default()">Click me</a>` Chrome ignores it. Maybe I'm putting it on the wrong place.

Comment: Change the order. You first have to prevent it before performing any other action. In any case, I recommend placing this in a dedicated JS file. Up to you

Comment: Even at the beginning doesn't work. I might redirect the onClick to a function and run that from there. Also, I'm running this locally, not on a server. This isn't a real matter, right? Because `history.back()` is just browser side.

Comment: @r0dr1 it's `event.preventDefault()`, not `prevent.default()`

Comment: Absolutely @Bergi! That indeed worked. Thank you so much!